# POSIX field splitting and double quotes behavior with `echo` and `for`

Tags: shell, scripting, posix

In light of the POSIX standard on [Field Splitting](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_05), [Double Quotes](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02_03), and the [for Loop](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_03) and the following example, I cannot understand why using double quotes in `echo "$s"` shows new lines between the numbers, whereas using double quotes in `for x in "$s"` does not show new lines between the numbers. Could someone please clarify?

```bsh
$ s=$(seq 1 4)
$ echo $s
1 2 3 4
$ echo "$s"
1
2
3
4
$ for x in $s; do echo $x; done
1
2
3
4
$ for x in "$s"; do echo $x; done
1 2 3 4
```

Comment: `for x in "$s"` doesn't "inhibit anything. It just sets `x` to the verbatim value of `$s` (including the newlines) --just once-- and then `echo $x` does the same thing as `echo $s` in the first example.

Comment: try with `for x in "$s"; do echo "<$x>"; done`

Comment: @user414777 I see; so you are saying that the verbatim value of `$s$` has newlines; and for `echo $s$` the newlines do not show because of the POSIX field splitting behavior? Specifically, setting `IFS='\0'` causes `echo $s` and `echo "$s"` to become identical.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you have correctly mentioned, the `IFS` (field splitting) environment variable plays an important role here. Normally, `IFS` is set to include `<space>`, `<tab>`, and `<newline>` characters. It means when no quotes are used on a variable, the shell interpreter will break it into separate arguments by `IFS` values whenever possible (it even squeezes the multiple `IFS` characters).

So, in your `s` variable, there is always the following value. The rest depends on the interpretation.

```
1<newline>2<newline>3<newline>4
```

In the first `for`, the shell splits `$s` before running the `for` and performs the loop four times. For the following `echo`, there is nothing additional to split, so each element gets printed on a single line (which is what `echo` does).

The second `for` will be run only once for the whole `s` value as stated above. What happens now is that the shell breaks the `s` variable by `IFS` before passing to `echo` (since no double quotes on `x`). It means that the `<newline>` characters will become irrelevant and each number is just a single argument. When `echo` obtains multiple arguments, it will print them in the same order separated by space characters.